# Spring Cloud Config Server - Security Details

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

I implemented spring cloud config server and pushed it to pivotal cloud foundry. I added the below listed security details in application.yml. I did a "get" on the config server endpoint without passing any security credentials. I am able to receive a successful response , but I was expecting it to return an error saying authentication details aren't passed. Please can you let me know what I am missing?

```
security:
  basic:
    enabled: true
  user:
    name: ctp_config
    password: ctp_config
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you using Spring Boot, try add to dependency 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'

Comment: Thanks @Sergey , I'll try